# how to input a binary image file while uploading profile image file to IBM Connections using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, payload, ibm-connections, binary-image

I am using REST client to upload a profile photo to IBM connections but i am struck at the part where you have to send binary image file along with the PUT request.  So far I've done this:-

```
request.put("https://servername.com"/profiles/photo.do?
        key="profileuserID"),
        ContentType:image/jpeg
```

i have tried to put insert image by encoding it into base64 format or adding into file field in REST client. But it always returns nothing. It does remove the previous profile picture but it doesnt upload the new one.

Now i want to ask how to include binary image file in the request payload?

Comment: you should send it as Binary

Comment: Those quotes look wrong

Comment: Thats what i want to ask,,,How to send it as binary and what should i send it against.Like in payload there are [key:value] pairs so what is the key name and in value should i just use base64 encoded image?? @PaulBastide